# Local copy of working site > admin work > pages all get 404

Tags: 404, localhost

We're taking over hosting a clients site, and I've downloaded a copy of the site and the database, and set up both in mamp.

I've adjusted the db config, and the '/admin/' area all works - however, if I go to 'index.php' i'm just getting a 404 page ('Status: 404 Page Not Found').

I've adjusted the paths in Global Template Preferences, and General Configuration, but to no avail.

Any ideas of where I should start looking to find the issue? I'm new to EE...

cheers

Comment: Are the site templates stored in the database or externally? Was there an htaccess file involved on the server?

Answer (score -1):

I not sure why, but i stumbled across 'Enable Strict URLs' in the global template settings, tried setting to 'no' and all the page appears...